# *args is giving me unknown trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

```
@Ava.command()
async def general(*args):
    await Ava.send_message(message.Object(id='207602020968955906'), args)

@Ava.command(aliases=['game'])
async def setgame(*args):
    await Ava.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='%s'% (args)))
```

I'm still fairly new to Python coding and working with APIs, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

This code should take the user input (following the command) and re-print it elsewhere (at the destination of the given ID).  However, when taking the user input, it seems to attach some weird punctuation.

'Hi' becomes ('Hi',) for example.  It is always the same punctuation.  I have tried two different methods of pulling args, as you can see above.  I've looked all over and can't find an answer to this- any idea why *args is working like this/how to get around it?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `args` is a tuple. `('Hi',)` is that tuple, with one element in it. It *has* to be a tuple because `*args` means you'll capture 0 or more arguments.

Comment: Why are you using `*args` for this?

Comment: Don't confuse the string representation of the tuple `args` with the actual data.  It has only added the extra characters to represent the type, just as quotes appear around the `'Hi'`, they are not part of the stored data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*args` captures 0 or more arguments, and stores those in a tuple. When your function is called with one argument, you get a tuple with that one element:

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...     print(args)
...
>>> foo('Hi')
('Hi',)
```

You are converting that tuple to a string, and doing so you include the whole tuple notation. Perhaps you could *join* the strings into one longer string, with spaces in between?

Like this:

```
name = ' '.join(args)
await Ava.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=name))
```

This does assume that all arguments to the function are always going to be strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response- I realised I'm an idiot and haven't been using *args correctly.  As a quick secondary question I suppose- how would I go about allowing a string with spaces to be counted?  Using sampleString instead of *args, it only accepts the first word in the string.

Comment: @KitSmith: Sounds like `Ava` splits commands for you and passes in the resulting words as separate arguments. I'm not familiar with Ava, look in their documentation?

Comment: @KitSmith: googling around, I don't see any `Ava` classes in relation to `discord` Python APIs, so I'm guessing this is a name in your own code. But again, you need to look at your library documentation, whatever is responsible for implementing the `.command()` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

That is simply how `tuples` of length 1 are represented:

```
>>> ('Hi', 'Bye')[:1]
('Hi',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing argument using `*args`

For example, in your case

`await Ava.send_message(message.Object(id='207602020968955906'), *args)`